# django table is cutoff half at the last row

Tags: html, django, templates, html-table

I create a list of rows with each item in the list (row) containing a list of individual cells in my view and pass that to the template and use this code to build my table

```
 <table style="border: 1px solid black">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        {% for th_ in htl %}
           <th style="border: 1px solid black"> {{th_|safe}} </th>
        {%endfor%}
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        {% for tl_ in mylist %}
            <tr>
            {% for td_ in tl_ %}
                <td style="border: 1px solid black"> {{td_|safe}} </td>
            {%endfor%}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>

        </table>
```

Th problem is that the very last row is cut of at an arbitrary column and no html is generated for the rest of the row and the table is not displayed with all data. If I add a couple more rows to the very same table than the last row (which is not the 5th from the end is displayed correctly but the very last row is truncated. Any ideas why this odd behaviour occur?

Comment: Post the output of the template so we can see where it gets cut off.

Comment: Just a hint, maybe you have an unclosed HTML tag in your data (td_ ?), or by any chance a "<" ?

Comment: Is the rest of the HTML page after the table generated and returned? Are you by any chance using a middleware that modifies the response after the template was generated? Are you using Django's ConditionalGetMiddleware?